# Looking for the android DatePicker with the "Set" and "Cancel" buttons

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm developing a TODO app for a project in school and there is an option to set a reminder  for each task. If the user wants to set a reminder there is a popup dialog With a DatePicker. 
I have the DatePicker with the "Done" button only and i want the user to be able to cancel from the popup dialog and not by pressing the "Back" button.

I guess this issue is related with the API level or something like that
Anyone?

P.S: It would be great if someone can point me to an open source for the datetimepicker in [here](http://www.google.co.il/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&tbo=d&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIL514IL514&biw=1360&bih=629&tbm=isch&tbnid=40kv2cjQt_SytM%3a&imgrefurl=http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/&docid=wuVL23P5vhhF3M&imgurl=http://datetimepicker.googlecode.com/files/datetimepicker.png&w=480&h=800&ei=kjrUUM60I4aSswbJw4CAAw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=418&sig=112898430480167732459&page=1&tbnh=153&tbnw=92&start=0&ndsp=27&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:86&tx=44&ty=67). Found it on google code but there's only a .PNG and a .apk downloads there.

Thanx!!

Comment: the source code is there with the given link. Check the `source` tab in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I built a custom dialog very similar to the one in the link above.
Feel free to use it, hope it would help someone.
The whole application code is in this url:
git://github.com/danielemesh/Remind.ME.git